# Pub Sub only works in one direction

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, zeromq, raspbian, pyzmq

So I am using the python bindings for ZeroMQ in an attempt to send messages to several raspberry pis on a network for an art project. The issue is that I am not receiving any messages on the raspberry pi. To make matters worse, I can:

- Publish messages from the raspberry pi and receive them on my laptop(osx)
- A REQ/REP model works in both directions (osx -> RPI and RPI -> osx)

I was thinking that it has something to do with the firewall on either device, which I disabled on both. No luck.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is my code:

> ZMQ Publisher

```
import time
import zmq


def main():
    port = 5563

    # Prepare our context and publisher
    context = zmq.Context()
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:" + str(port))

    while True:
        # Write two messages, each with an envelope and content
        publisher.send_multipart([b"A", b"We don't want to see this"])
        publisher.send_multipart([b"B", b"We would like to see this"])
        time.sleep(1)

    # We never get here but clean up anyhow
    publisher.close()
    context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> ZMQ Subscriber

```
import zmq
import sys


def main():
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    port = 5563
    string = "tcp://" + ip + ":" + str(port)

    # Prepare our context and publisher
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    subscriber.connect(string)
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"B")

    while True:
        # Read envelope with address
        [address, contents] = subscriber.recv_multipart()
        print("[%s] %s" % (address, contents))

    # We never get here but clean up anyhow
    subscriber.close()
    context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Works fine as-is for me. Double check your ip perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, it had to do with the version of pyzmq.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There were two issues:

First- Since I am using python3, I had to make sure I was using pip-3.2 commands when updating/installing python modules

Second- On my laptop I was using pyzmq 14.6.0 and I was using 2.2.0 on the PI. I had updated it, but used pip instead of pip-3.2. Once I properly updated pyzmq it worked as expected.